# XML Schema is not validating

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, schema

I am working on XML and Schemas. I need help validating my schema, as when I put it in an online validator, I get an error of: S4s-elt-must-match.1: The Content Of 'sequence' Must Match (annotation?, (element | Group | Choice | Sequence | Any)*). A Problem Was Found Starting At: ComplexType.

I am using the Russian Doll design, as this seems to be the one I like the most.

catalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<catalog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="catalog.xsd">
   <photo cid="c1749" donatedBy="John Borelli">
      <name metadata="tunis cooper property museum">Tunis R. Cooper property</name>
      <description>
      <![CDATA[ 
         A more recent picture of the property taken by the Borelli family.  The property is listed in the 
         National and New Jersey Registers of Historic Places.
      ]]>
      </description>
      <date>circa 1950</date>
      <images>
         <img src="1749a.jpg" />
      </images>
   </photo>

   <photo cid="c1411" donatedBy="Saint Johns Catholic Church">
      <name metadata="saint johns catholic church">Saint Johns Church</name>
      <description>
      <![CDATA[ 
         A more recent picture of the property taken by the Borelli family.  The property is listed in the 
         National and New Jersey Registers of Historic Places.
      ]]>
      </description>      
      <date>1921</date>
   </photo>
</catalog>
```

catalog.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>     
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="catalog">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="photo"/>
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="data" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="images">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:element name="img"/>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:attribue name="cid" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:attribue name="donatedBy" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:attribue name="metadata" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:attribue name="src" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>    
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a couple of errors in your XSD. And one in your XML.

To remove this one error in your XML, change the namespace in the `<catalog...>` element from `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Instance"` to `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`. A simple typo.

And your XSD should look like this to validate your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>     
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="catalog">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="photo" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>                        
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="name">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="metadata" type="xs:string"/>
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>                                
                            </xs:element>                            
                            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="date" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="images" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="img"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>                            
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="cid" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="donatedBy" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="metadata" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="src" type="xs:string"/>                        
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>                
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>    
</xs:schema>
```

What I changed was:

1. The element `photo` occurs more than one time, so I added `maxOccurs="unbounded"`
2. The element `name` can have an attribute, so I changed its definition to a `complexType` with `simpleContent`.
3. The element `images` does not have to occur, hence I added `minOccurs="0"`
4. I moved the attributes out of the `xs:sequence` into the `xs:complexType`

Now the XSD should validate your XML.